# How to disable mipmaps in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, mipmaps

I am making 2D sprite engine in OpenGL and I want to disable mipmaps, as I do not need them.

When I call:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, internal->internal_w, internal->internal_h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, internal->data);
RenderWithThisTexture();
```

I got white rect, but when I call:

```
gluBuild2DMipmaps(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_RGBA, internal->internal_w, internal->internal_h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, internal->data);
RenderWithThisTexture();
```

I got the properly textured rect

I figured out that this may be because of enabled mipmaps, but sadly I can't find any info how I can disable them.

I want to stick with OpenGL 1.1 (not OGL 2.0 or above code)

Comment: I hope you mean OpenGL 1.1 and not 1.0, as the former doesn't support texture objects, which makes texturing very inefficient and cumbersome to use. I assume you're not speaking of ES either, as otherwise the question needs retagging/retitling anyway.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

This should be the default. Make sure you are not changing it to `MIPMAP` somewhere.

Comment: It is actually not the default. Strangely enough the default value is `GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR`, which indeed enables mipmapping. And by the way, you should put out that you can also set it to `GL_NEAREST` depending on the OP's needs, just nothing with `MIPMAP` in it.